# Having a foreign key referring multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a `tableB`, whose Primary Key`(colB1)` refers to a PK of `tableA`. I did it like this:

```
 tableA(colA1(pk), colA2)

 tableB(colB1(pk), colB2)

 tableC(colC1(pk), colC2)

 foreign key (`colB1`) references tableA(`colA1`)
   on delete cascade 
       on update cascade
```

Now, I also want the same foreign key`(colB)` to refer to `colC` of `tableC`. This is the way I know:

```
foreign key (`colB1`) references tableA(`colA1`)
   on delete cascade 
       on update cascade,
foreign key (`colB1`) references tableC(`colC1`)
   on delete cascade 
       on update cascade
```

Since I am doing it on an existing table, I just want to confirm if it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: As far as I know, `foreign key ("col1")` must be preceded by `constraint "ctr1"` - and you can not have 2 constraints with the same name on a single table (so put different name on each of the foreign key constraints)

Comment: @IVOGELOV :Thanks for replying, may be because I had a single constraint, I got away without naming it. Now, that I need 2, I might have to name them as you suggested.

Comment: Have you tested this? Not sure how the multiple cascaded deletes will work. Will the second one fail? Not sure.